# Calculating a camera's normal in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm making a first person shooter game with OpenGL, and I'm trying to offset the creation of a physics rigid body (using the Bullet library), so that the rigid body is always created where the camera is looking rather than always at a set point in front of the camera.

Apparently, one way of doing this is by creating a 3x3 rotation matrix or a quat from the view matrix and multiplying that by a forward vector to get a normal that points to where the camera looks.

However, I'm unsure about how to get these values (the quat from the view matrix, what the forward vector would be, whether or not I have to normalise the result of the multiplication etc.). I've tried looking at tutorials but I'm still unsure about getting these values.

Comment: You should probably be storing a 3x3 matrix for your camera, then the vector you want is just the 3rd column.  This is what I do anyway, since the camera is part of the scene and composes an object transform just like any other object in the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually quite close and `cameraPos` should be correct. Given that you have the inverse view matrix, then the camera's normal/direction is just the column prior to the camera's position.

Here's some pseudo GLSL-like code:

```
mat4 inv = inverse(view);

vec3 pos = vec3(inv[3]);
vec3 dir = -vec3(inv[2]);
```

Where `view` is the camera's view matrix (`mat4`).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So is the normal just "vec3 norm = dir * pos;"? If so then do you know how I'd use the normal to offset the creation of a rigidbody? It's currently just given the camera's position (x, y, z), but I need the rigidbodies to always be created in front of the camera (regardless of it's orientation), which is why I'm using the normal.

Comment: If by normal you're referring to the direction the camera is facing, then that's what `dir` is in this case. So if you want to create an offset position you do `new_pos = pos + dir * offset` where offset is a length say `10`. Then `new_pos` will be 10 units away from `pos` in the direction of `dir`.

Comment: Fantastic, you've just helped me fix a long standing issue. I tried using a vec3 to offset it since I want it offset by (0.3, 0, 2) but that's something I can probably figure out. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this actually. Multplying the direction by an offset moves it forward, but what about moving it to the right of left? I basically want to offset my rigidbody backwards AND to the right, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to move it backwards then move it to the right, or all in all just rotating it about to the right from behind?

Comment: I'm just trying to move the object a bit closer to the camera and also slightly to the right, in any order. So long as rather than the object always appearing at the centre of the view, it always appears to the right of the centre and slightly closer to the camera, if that makes sense.